# How to cross the Animated Forest?

Tags: adom

What are some tactics to safely cross the Animated Forest in ADOM? I've got a level 9 troll barbarian with 44/26 DV/PV, and controlled teleportation but no way to teleport.

Comment: Nevermind... I converted the altar in the Dwarftown, angered the priest, who attacked me. Killed the priest, then Waldenbrook came in and pwned me dead. Lol.

Comment: Don't use fire spells.  You anger every tree that can see you.  Of course, if you have enough spells and mana, then go wild and rake in the XP!

Comment: @ElliotBonneville been there, converted that. In a separate but related incident, I put on a "Leather Armor of Hate" in Dwarftown and learned about the Hate suffix.  Got smacked down pretty hard that time too.

Comment: @Ben haha that'll do it. Also annoying is the similar aura you can get from that corruption. I've had that end a good few games as well.

Answer (score 3):

For a melee-focused non-caster, the easiest strategy is to set your defensive tactics to Coward and rest in place until you get a chance to move between the trees. It's very tedious and there's always the possibility that they'll gang up on you for no reason, but it's doable.

Answer (score 2):

Go through the Dwarven Halls instead.  Go far, go fast, and don't slow down for any monster!

(I realize this doesn't answer your question, but whenever I try walking through the Animated Forest, I end up fighting some trees.  Either some fraction of them are hostile, or I'm clumsy; could be either.  And once you start fighting trees, you can't *stop*, because fighting the hostile trees angers the non-hostile trees - and it's hard to tell which ones are hostile, from the up-to-eight trees surrounding you.  Plus, trees spawn with time, so the level will eventually end up either impassable or violently logged.)

Comment: Mm, yeh. Since I asked this question I played a lot of ADOM. I've come to the conclusion that it's only worth doing the AF if you're invisible, double-shield-wearing, can teleport, and have teleport control. Of course, if you're that strong, there's not much of a risk in taking DH. :)

Answer (score 2):

Equip two shields and just hold down in the direction you wish to go. The Dwarven Halls can generate some really scary monsters. The forest is much safer.

Comment: You get an awful lot of angry trees this way, and you won't do much damage while double-shielding. Is there a minimum level or recommended class for this method? Do the trees eventually move out of the way? What makes this work?

Comment: you don't do any damage while equipping two shields, so you never make any trees angry... yes, trees eventually move out of the way, as trees move in a random pattern. If you are patient enough and have enough food you can do it.

Comment: Alex, edit your answer to include why your method works; it'll make for a much better answer. (Comments are transitory; they won't always stick around.)

Answer (score 1):

Alex's answer is a good one, but I'd like to expand slightly to explain why it works and what to do in some edge cases.

As Alex suggested, the *safest* way to pass the Animated Forest (by conventional means, anyways) is to equip two tower shields and set tactics to Coward. This works because, by equipping two shields, you will no longer auto-attack the neutral trees if you bump into them. Note that there is no confirmation of whether you actually want to attack when bumping into trees - you will just swing your sword. With two shields, however, this is disabled, as you cannot attack with a shield.

Coward mode grants extra defensive protection, to help you survive the rare hostile tree or other beastie that spawns. Fortunately, there will not be a lot of either of these, as the trees tend to squash anything hostile to them, which is most spawns.

As for movement: Patience. Wait in place until you have a move you can take. I suggest moving any time you have a chance to move in the general direction of the stairs you want, and AVOID THE WALLS if possible, as it is easy to get trapped there. You will occasionally find yourself trapped - cornered against a wall or simply surrounded in the open. Most of the time you can just wait a few turns and then move, but over time you will collect an entourage of hostile trees. If they get too numerous, you'll have to pull out a sword and kill a couple, otherwise you will find yourself completely trapped and unable to move as hostile trees will never move away from you. Just be careful - don't upset trees you don't need to.

Lastly, food is a major concern here, as it takes a long time to cross the forest, so bring extra.